# Meteor: change a user password WITHOUT logout?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Accounts.setPassword(userId, password);

Before Meteor v1.0.2, the user was not logout when calling this function.

Since v1.0.2, I quote from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md, "Expire a user's password reset and login tokens in all circumstances when their password is changed".

I don't know the reason of this change,but the fact is that function above logout the user.

Is there a way, with v1.0.2, to change a user password without logout the user?

If not, how do I downgrade the package account-base so the behaviour is like before?

Thanks.

Comment: https://atmospherejs.com/i/installing

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use `Accounts.changePassword` ([docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_changepassword)) to change the password instead, this will not affect the user's existing tokens (as from) https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L299-L302

If you want to do this from the server without knowing the existing password you would have to fork the `accounts-password` package and remove this line: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-password/password_server.js#L338 and add this package into the `/packages` directory of your app

If you want to downgrade your package (so long as the version you're using of meteor supports it):

```
meteor remove accounts-password
meteor add accounts-password@1.0.3
```

Comment: I've used Accounts.changePassword instead. It's a bit more messy, it's on the client side, but it works. Thanks.

Comment: The better answer is down below by @romaroma

Answer (score 21):

```
Accounts.setPassword(userId, password, options)
```

This method now [supports](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_setpassword) `options` parameter that includes `options.logout` option which could be used to prevent the current user's logout.

Comment: this should be the real answer. Thx!

Answer (score 5):

The above answer is correct and here's the exact copy-paste code in case you're struggling:

```
Accounts.setPassword(userId, password, {logout: false});
```

Note: make sure you are doing this call server side.

Comment: This simply restates information already available in one of the existing answers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I clarified why I wrote this answer.